# Print HTML Title to the console window using F# + Canopy

Tags: f#, canopy-web-testing

I've utilized the following links for reference, but still cannot get my code to print the HTML

```
<title>This is the title</title>
```

[Using Selenium Code with F# Canopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678029/using-selenium-code-with-f-canopy)

http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/actions.html

The following 3 lines of code do not print what I am expecting (I am attempting C# at the end as another way to do this). What I had expected this to do, was extract the TITLE from my HTML file and print it to the console window. I do not have a "purpose" for this yet, but I was just testing all of the actions available in the documentation.

```
let theTitle = title()
printfn "Page title is: %s" title()
System.Console.WriteLine("Print the title here: {0}", theTitle);
```

Comment: When you say, do not print what I am expecting it is good to show what they actually do print.

Comment: I've edited the question with more detail in what I was "expecting" to see. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code:

```
let title() = @"<title>This is the title</title>"
printfn "Page title is: %s" (title())
Page title is: <title>This is the title</title>
```

I get the expected result.  Due to F# type inference restrictions, you need to use a pair of brackets around `title()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have applied this and it does in fact print to the console window. I have also edited my question with details on what I was expecting.